# Angular 2 + mvc core: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I'm trying to build a new angular 2 and I'm running into an issue where my component templates are throwing 404 errors and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

I can configure a component and specify the template but for reasons that are currently escaping me I keep seeing the templates being referenced as .js files in the console.

for example I see the following error:

> Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:5000/app/app.html.js
>       wrapFn@http://localhost:5000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:34
>       invokeTask@http://localhost:5000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:40
>       runTask@http://localhost:5000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:57
>       invoke@http://localhost:5000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:40
>       Error loading http://localhost:5000/app/app.html.js as "app/app.html" from http://localhost:5000/app/app.component.js

Now I know I don't have an app.html.js, but I can't figure out why angular is trying to load a file that doesn't exist. Further more its only adds to confusion when I know I'm explicitly setting my template to app.html as such

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

const template = require("./app/app.html");

@Component({
  selector: "alerts",
  template: template
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public router: Router) {}
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

*edit*
Just to rule out the component I've also simplified it by removing the external template and put the template markup directly into the component and I still get the same results, angular is looking for a file thats neither referenced or existing:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "alerts",
  template: `<alerts></alerts>`
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public router: Router) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A much easier way to do this would be to use the `moduleId:module.id,` and therefore not require the require

```
@Component({
  moduleId:module.id, // this makes the .html relative to the folder you are in
  selector: "alerts",
  templateUrl: app.html
})
```